# Do I need to group data for linear regression model?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I have a dependent variable, Y, and an independent variable, X. X (independent variable) is velocity. There are four values 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55 m/s. Whereas Y (dependent variable) is time. There are between 35-40 time values for each velocity value.

I want to build a linear model with logarithmic scales (basically modelling a power law).

Do I have to take the mean of the time values for each velocity value and then run linear regression, or should I build the linear model with the cluster of points?

What is the right approach in this case?

Thank you

Comment: Generally speaking, no, you’ll want to run the regression on your raw data, not aggregates. If your data have dependencies (e.g., multilevel/nested or repeated measures), you would want to account for that by including random effects. Hard to say more without seeing your data.

Answer (score 2):

### Balanced data

Both give the same coefficients with balanced data -- I couldn't tell from the question if that is what you have since the input was missing. Basically what you are losing by summarization is the variation that occurs within group but that does not affect the coefficients.  Here is an example:

```
# generate balanced test data
set.seed(123)
x <- c( 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55 )
xx <- rep(x, each = 3)
y <- xx + rnorm(12)
DF12 <- data.frame(x = log(xx), y = log(y + 1))

DF4 <- aggregate(y ~ x, DF12, mean)  # summarized data

coef(lm(y ~ x, DF4))    
## (Intercept)           x 
##  0.06932553 -0.33797974 

coef(lm(y ~ x, DF12))
## (Intercept)           x 
##  0.06932553 -0.33797974
```

On the other hand the 12 row data frame will have more degrees of freedom so it would be better able to detect various items.

### Unbalanced data

For unbalanced data we can use weights.

```
# unbalanced data
DF11 <- head(DF12, -1)
DF4.11 <- aggregate(y ~ x, DF11, mean)

coef(lm(y ~ x, DF11))
## (Intercept)           x 
##  -0.3007732  -0.7768963 

coef(lm(y ~ x, DF4.11, weight = c(3, 3, 3, 2)))
## (Intercept)           x 
##  -0.3007732  -0.7768963
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have some doubts to clarify. 
When we use mean to summarize the data (in my case, where I have four values for x), we use only 4 data points to build a linear regression model. Is it possible to make a linear model with only 4 points? Is not it questionable, per se?

Comment: If you have fewer points then you get fewer degrees of freedom, as mentioned.

Comment: Understood. One more thing I am confused about. 
If I use mean or raw data, even though coefficients are the same, the p-value is significant (p < 0.05) when I use raw data but not significant when I use summarized means for the groups. 
So the model is significant for slope in one case and not in the other. How can I explain this, and which one is the right model?

Comment: YEs, of course. The degress of freedom are larger in the raw model as pointed out already.